# Need To Make A NSMutableArray That Is Writable To Disk

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to have a table view that is blank at start.

The user will be able to add entries and sub entries to design a workout routine.

For example, table is blank at first, then user adds "Day 1", and adds bench press, bicep curl, etc. into this Day 1 sub table.  Then he adds a Day 2, and adds some other exercises in there.

I already have all these strings that user can choose from in a plist that is loaded into a different table that just sorts these strings my muscle group.  What is the best way to go about this?

I hope my question is clear if not I will try better to reword it.

Comment: Well that depends on the object that are in de NSMutableArray. If all object are implementing the NSCoding protocol then you can use NSKeyedArchiver to create a NSData object of your Array and write this to disk.

Comment: Thanks, rckoenes.  So far I have just made the plist that has all the exercises etc that the user can choose from.  I have not done anything other than that with regards to data.  I'm new to this and the data aspect is somewhat confusing so I'm still reading about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar where I actually just wrote the contents of my array out to a PLIST file and steered clear of the keyed archiver.  You can't use this approach if you have custom objects in your array.  I believe your array (or dictionary) contents can only be of type nsstring, nsnumber, nsdata, nsarray, nsdate and nsdictionary (there could be more?!?).

I have a singleton that controls loading and writing the data from/to local storage.  It also contains the single array object that I manipulate from my various view controllers.

Within init, I load my array property (deep mutable copy is a category method I've built for nssarray):

```
- (void) loadYourArray {
NSArray *tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[Utils getFileStorageLocation]];
if (tempArray == nil) {
    yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
} else {
    yourArray = [[NSArray deepMutableCopy:tempArray] retain];
}}
```

when I'm ready to save my data, I simply call a persist method:

```
- (void)persistYourArray:(BOOL)broadcast {
[yourArray writeToFile:[Utils getFileStorageLocation] atomically:YES];

if (broadcast) {
    // notify some peeps
}}
```

Comment: yes my array would just be nsdates and nsstrings, etc.  I'm going to look into this, thanks!